# Repeating common strings in a long batch script

Tags: bash

I am inexperienced with Bash and scripting in general. I am writing a script involving aws CLI, for which the commands output an id. See below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Command 1

VAR1=$(aws ec2 create-vpc --query "Vpc.VpcId" --output text)

# Command 2

VAR2=$(aws ec2 create-subnet --query "Subnet.SubnetId" --output text)
```

The output of the aws ec2 commands will be something like "id-ffffffff", which I've now captured via $VAR1 and $VAR2

I now want to output the result of each command to the console, but display different messages based on the result of the command. So far, I've done it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR1=$(aws ec2 create-vpc --query "Vpc.VpcId" --output text)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo VPC created successfully... ${VAR1}
else
    echo "Command failed"
fi

# Command 2

VAR2=$(aws ec2 create-subnet --query "Subnet.SubnetId" --output text)

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo Subnet created successfully... ${VAR2}
else
    echo "Command failed"
fi
```

The problem is now that I have many lines like the ones I'm using above (10+) and I can't help but think It's silly to repeatedly run the same if/else statement for each line.

Should I use something like a goto? What is best practice here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Create a function

```
report () {
    if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$2"
    else
        echo "Command failed"
    fi

}

VAR1=$(aws ec2 create-vpc --query "Vpc.VpcId" --output text)

report $? "$VAR1"

VAR2=$(aws ec2 create-subnet --query "Subnet.SubnetId" --output text)

report $? "$VAR2"
```

It seems you can create a function for the `aws ec2` as well.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the right idea. It doesn't seem to offer me the ability to add unique strings of text depending on the command though... how would I adjust the line.... **report $? "$VAR1"** to echo a more descriptive output such as "VPC successfully created... "$VAR1". This would differ from the subnet command, as I would want the output for the subnet to be "Subnet successfully created... "$VAR2". Hope this makes sense...

Comment: Just add another parameter to the function.

Comment: Possibly, define an associative array of the texts where the index is a short-form name for the message.